# How to safely and cleanly rewrite critical/production code?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, refactoring

I have some critical production routines need to be rewritten from scratch. Take a simple example:

```
public class ProductionClass {
    public IList<Values> WillBeFiredIfThisBreaks(Input input) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The input object has way too many permutations to unit test thoroughly, and I want to play it safe because these routines are heavily used everyday. So, my thought was to:

1) Rename and mark the current implementation as obsolete.

2) Write a new implementation that falls back on the old one if there are any issues (see below)

3) Remove the old implementation after the new one has been running in prod for a month or two without issues.

```
public class ProductionClass {

    public IList<Values> WillBeFiredIfThisBreaks(Input input) {
       try{
          var ret = NewImpl(input);
       } catch(Exception){
          ret = null;
       }

       if(ret == null || ret.Count == 0){
          Log.Error("NewImpl Failed! Inputs: {0}", inputs);
          return OldImpl(input);
       }
       return ret;
    }


    public IList<Values> NewImpl(Input input) {
       ...
    }

    [Obsolete("Rewritten 03/18/2013, throw away once NewImpl confirmed stable", false)]
    public IList<Values> OldImpl(Input input) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The above approach is a bit ugly in that I'll have to go through and recreate this logic for every method that I need to rewrite. (And I'll correspondingly need to remove the fallback logic and delete the obsolete methods in every location when the new code is confirmed stable). So my question is: Are there any .NET frameworks or design patterns which make this sort of "ultra-paranoid" code rewrite a bit more elegant?

Comment: "The input object has way too many permutations to unit test thoroughly" - if that's true then how will you write a new version taking  less parameters?

Comment: How many permutations of the `Input` object is "too many"?

Comment: Remember that there are ways for code to fail that don't involve exceptions.

Comment: There is a good book on this topic - [Working effectively with legacy code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052), [initial article](http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode.pdf) on this topic. Basically: add tests, than change code and not ever keep old/commented out code.

Comment: I think it's bad to have the two "implementations" in such a fallback pattern. Replace it. Replace it entirely. Use tests to find the edge cases and ensure the reference contract is well specified. If the new method does something different (excluding bugs or lack-of which tests should catch), then it's a different method and not a different implementation of the same method.

Comment: Hi Mitch, I don't understand your question - the old and new versions take the same input parameter, only the method itself is changing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. In principle I totally agree with all of the comments that say code should be cleanly replaced, letting the unit tests validate the integrity of the implementation. I just think its unreasonable to stick to that ideology for these ultra-critical sections. It's the difference between the code breaking outright vs. getting benign errors in our logs which we can comfortably fix and write unit tests for. In other words, I'm unwilling to cause unnecessary production outages when I can help it.

Comment: joelt - Thanks, that is true. The check I do for 0 elements in the sample is supposed to demonstrate that I'm checking for more than just exceptions.

Comment: Normally I'm not a zealot about unit tests. However, if you're writing code to catch all possible error permutations anyway...writing tests might not be that much more work.

Comment: This question is a bad fit for stackoverflow; see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. You may get better responses on programmers.se or codereview.se

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for a pattern, a possible response is to use AOP with method weaving. But a better response would be concentrate your effort in creating the unit test.